# i have a project where i need to make special routing how i can make my own rule?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

in my own site i need a thing that page are known by #topic.

it's need to look like

mywebsite.com#google [are this possible i need to pass google as parameter]
OR
mywebsite.com/#google [if first can not be done then how i can use it]

how i can apply this thing in my website. the thing i need to done that

if anyone open the site mywebsite.com#google that the content genrate dynamically through [passing google as parameter]

can anyone show how i can make routing for this

Comment: that's going to be difficult, as # is used to indicate the "fragment", or anchor name element on the page. why not use "?"?

Comment: question mark means something like question and # means look on detail so i prefer to use #. can you show some alternative for that

Comment: yes, as I posted in a comment, you can urlencode your links to mywebsite.com%23google

Comment: @Moby: It appears that you want to change the meaning of ? and # in URL's. Don't fight http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986, embrace it. Use ? instead of # and your problem suddenly goes away.

Comment: @Moby: Since you don't like the question mark and # can't be used, why don't you just use / as everyone else (even Google)? And you know what? It will work in Asp.net MVC as well. And BTW: ? and URLs are not interpreted as questions as you (as human) interpret them or emotionally feel them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use routing for this. The value that follows the # sign in an URL is NEVER sent to the server by the client browser. So for example if you request `http://example.com/someaction#google` the server can never fetch the value `google` simply because the browser never sends it. The only way is to use javascript (`window.location.hash`) and maybe send an AJAX request to the server by rewriting the url : `http://example.com/someaction?param=google`

Comment: yeah i found that chrome make them /#google instead of #google. are their any alterantive can help me to done this thing.

Comment: @Moby, no, this doesn't change anything. You need javascript and that's the only way. No need to waste your time with routing.

Comment: if you urlescape it to %23 it will go to the server, but I don't know if that will help

Comment: @comeau_ictx, yes sure, but that will change the URL. It's no longer a fragment which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: maybe, but it's hard to know (for me anyway) what he really wants!

Comment: @darin i thing you are right. i need to making this using ajax well thanks a lot .

Answer (score -1):

You have the route table at Global.asax. Add this on the method RegisterRoutes. I am not so sure if it will work as I didn't test but that can give you a good start.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "RouteWithSharp",
            "#{page}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: if you mention my comment same thing i already try. thanks but it's not worked.